# Where should my angular service do it's data fetch so data is loaded and ready to be shared by multiple controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service that fetches data that will be used by multiple controllers. I only want to fetch the data from the db once and then have the service store the data in an object which controllers can reference through the service.

I'm using ui-router with multiple and nested views. Where should I put my service fetch so that my controllers can safely reference the data knowing the service fetched it successfully?

For example, where would I put this:

```
myAngularService.GetDbData(DataId).success(function (response) {
            this.myDbData = response;
        });
```

So that in my controllers I can do this:

```
angular.module('myWebApp.controllers').
    controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myAngularService) {
        $scope.myDbData = myAngularService.myDbData;
    });
```

I thought about using a resolve in my main state that houses all my other substates, however I'm not sure how to pass a parameter to my service that way (in this example the parameter would be `DataId`).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in the service itself if you'd like so that the service call will only be made once.  The controllers don't have to know anything about how the data is being returned.

```
//pseudo code
function GetDbData(DataId) {
    if(previouslyReceivedData) {
        return previouslyReceivedData;
    } else {
        previouslyReceivedData = $http.whateverCallYouNeedToRetrieveTheData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go one step further and use `$rootScope.$broadcast` so that if a controller tries to grab the data before it has been retrieved it will be notified when the data actually becomes available.

Comment: Couldn't this result in multiple redundant calls to $http.whateverCallYouNeedToRetrieveTheData(); if multiple controllers attempt to access the data in rapid succession before it's loaded?

Comment: It would result in redundant calls to the $http service if multiple calls come in before one of them resolves.  To handle that case you'd have to implement some sort of debounce functionality so that all calls coming in could "subscribe" to one promise and all receive the data from that one call.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a promise so the service always return the same type of variable (an unresolved promise in this case).

Comment: This is the best solution that angular has to offer? Seems kinda hacked together. I guess I thought there was a simple choke point in the load process where I could make a synchronous call to the fetch and then reliably access the data without a bunch of callbacks and broadcasts.

Comment: I don't see the need for a broadcast at all, and it's only if you're worried about multiple simultaneous calls that you need to implement the debounce pattern.